# Highlighting using Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets, I have tried multiple ways to get the following to occur. I need the conditional formula to be IF(C3:C1000 contain text,and E2:E1000 is missing a date, then E2:E100 needs to be highlighted).

Apply to range:
  E2:E1003

Format Rules:
Format cells if...
Custom Formula is

```
IF($C2:$C1003="text",$E2:$E1003="empty")
```

Formatting Style
Highlight in Yellow

I've tried rewriting that text multiple ways and nothing

And I can't get it to highlight any of the cells in Column E that are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=IF((LEN(C3))*(E3=""), 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the help